Inaccurate calculation of aggregate functions in Postgres
When calculating aggregate functions with columns with the DOUBLE PRECISION data type, inaccurate values are obtained.
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE GROUP_TEST(TEXT_COLUMN TEXT, DOUBLE_COLUMN DOUBLE PRECISION);

INSERT INTO GROUP_TEST VALUES ('some value', 100.1);
INSERT INTO GROUP_TEST VALUES ('some value', 200.2);

SELECT TEXT_COLUMN, SUM(DOUBLE_COLUMN), AVG(DOUBLE_COLUMN) FROM GROUP_TEST GROUP BY TEXT_COLUMN;

Postgres returned these values



text_column
sum
avg




some value
300.29999999999995
150.14999999999998



I expected these values:



text_column
sum
avg




some value
300.3
150.15



How do I get the correct values? I can't predict exactly what number after the point to round to, because different values ​​may occur.

Does this answer your question? Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?, Is floating-point math broken?

Use type numeric instead of double precision. The former is exact, the latter isn't. Numeric can also hold larger values.

I have found a solution to the problem. Thanks to Zegarek for the idea.
SELECT TEXT_COLUMN, SUM(DOUBLE_COLUMN::NUMERIC)::DOUBLE PRECISION, AVG(DOUBLE_COLUMN::NUMERIC)::DOUBLE PRECISION FROM GROUP_TEST GROUP BY TEXT_COLUMN;

Better don't store doubles in the first place. Alter the column type to store numeric values, then you don't need to adjust your query
